# How to Delete a table Row with Delete Button

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm so sorry for my bad english and such Basic Question.
I would like to ask:

Assuming I have displayed table with 6 columns and rows of values.
At the end of columns I have "Option Title" and rows have Option as "DELETE Button".

Like this:
Complete table

[image]

What I want is when I click the Delete button all values on rows selected are completely deleted.

Like this:
After delete

[image]

Here is my PHP and HTML code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
        <?php
             while($getdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
             {
             echo"<td>".$getdata['x_id']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$getdata['x_title']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$getdata['x_track']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$getdata['x_tag']."</td>";
             echo"<td>".$getdata['x_model']."</td>";
             echo'<td><img class="img-table-thumbnail" src="'.$getdata['x_thumb'].'"></td>';
             echo'<td><a type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="'.$getdata['x_link'].' " target="_BLANK">VISIT</a></td>'; 
             echo'<td><form action="delete.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <button type="submit" name="deleteData" class="btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
             </form></td>';
             echo "</tr>";
             }

             //$result = mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql);

             $db_connect->Close();
             ?>
  </tbody>
```

and delete.php:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];

$update = $db_connect->prepare("DELETE FROM $db_table WHERE id = ?");
$update->bind_param('i', $id);
$update->execute();
$update->close(); 


header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Looking for help and thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: I'm missing where you send the $_GET['id'] in your HTML. In delete.php $id what value get $id?

Comment: You should include the id into the form, because now it does not post anything. But you can also insert a hidden input into the form that's value is set by java script by clicking on the row's id for example. Secondly, `$_POST` != `$_GET`

Comment: Probably i missed $_GET['id'] , but when i change to $_GET['x_id'], it still nothing happens. @Antonio Milo

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code:

**NOTE: I haven't seen the complete code, but I have changed the code where there is wrong assignments/declarations. you can feel free to adjust the code**

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <?php
        while($getdata = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo"<td>".$getdata['x_id']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$getdata['x_title']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$getdata['x_track']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$getdata['x_tag']."</td>";
            echo"<td>".$getdata['x_model']."</td>";
            echo'<td><img class="img-table-thumbnail" src="'.$getdata['x_thumb'].'"></td>';
            echo'<td><a type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="'.$getdata['x_link'].' " target="_BLANK">VISIT</a></td>'; 
            echo'<td><form action="delete.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <button type="submit" name="deleteData" class="btn-sm btn-primary" value=".$getdata['x_id']."><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </form></td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        //$result = mysqli_query($db_connect,$sql);

        $db_connect->Close();
    ?>
```

Delete.php

```
$id = (int)$_POST['deleteData'];

$update = $db_connect->prepare("DELETE FROM $db_table WHERE id = ?");
$update->bind_param('i', $id);
$update->execute();
$update->close(); 


header("location:index.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using POST as requestmethod on delete.php. Doing so, you get your id by $_POST['id'] and not by $_GET['id']. But in your case you do not have any form control that holds that value.

See [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
and [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Now you have two options.

1.) Change your form by renaming the button to "id" and set it's value attribute to $getdata['your_field_with_id']. Inside delete.php you than have to change $_GET['id'] into $_POST['id'] because you're sending the formdata by POST and not GET.

```
echo '
<td>
    <form action="delete.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button type="submit" name="id" value="', $getdata['your_field_with_id'], '" class="btn-sm btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> DELETE
        </button>
     </form>
</td>';
```

2.) Replace the col with your form with the following code

```
echo '
<td>
    <a href="delete.php?id=', $getdata['your_field_with_id'], '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> DELETE
    </a>
</td>';
```

As you can see I remove the form an replace it by by a simple link, that holds the id of the record.

Personally, I would prefer the second solution over the first.